# differential equation system order

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, dynamical-systems, systems-of-equations

my question is very easy:
I started study dynamic systems and I have this system:

$Mz_1''(t) +\beta z_1'(t) = F(t)$

$Mz_2''(t) - \beta z_2'(t)+kz_2(t)=\beta z_1'(t)$

where $ M, \beta, k $ are constants and ' is the order of diff. equation.

Now I have to choose the state variables, that they are as the order of the system.
Which is the order of this system?
4 or 2? So how much state variables can I choose?

Regards

Comment: solve the first equation and  substitute it in the second equation and then solve the second equation

Comment: I tryed to find $ z_1' $ and substitute it in the second equation, but I still have $z_1''$ .

Comment: Do you know how to get the complementary solution and the particular solution?

Comment: I don't  solve the system  I have to choose the order  of the system  and then  choose  the state variables  and write  i / s / o rappresentation of the mechanical system

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Generally each differentiation can be selected as a state variable. You have two second order differential equations, which should give 4 state variables. There are of course infinitely many choices of state variables, but the easiest one is

$$ x_1 = z_1, x_2 = z_1', x_3 = z_2, x_4 = z_2' $$

Now, can you write this in matrix form as follows:

$$\begin{bmatrix}x_1' \\ x_2' \\ x_3' \\ x_4'\end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix}* & * & * & * \\ * & * & * & * \\ * & * & * & * \\ * & * & * & * \end{bmatrix} \begin{bmatrix}x_1 \\ x_2 \\ x_3 \\ x_4\end{bmatrix} + \begin{bmatrix}* \\ * \\ * \\ *\end{bmatrix}$$

Can you find what each * should be?

Comment: Yes! This is what I asked! Yesterday I solved the system in the same mode, but I had got a doubt about the number of state variables! Thank you very much!